# How to do perform where clause for multiple columns

Tags: sql

I am trying to filter based on corresponce type and then filter when an OL ocurred more than 7 days after an IL (correspondence type) based on the enterted date.

This is in a sql database. I am having some issues linking the correspondence type and the entered date to show only those that are greater than the 7 days from the IL (type)

```
SELECT  [ID]
,[EnteredDate]
,[CorrespondenceType]
FROM [PRXXXXXXXX] 
WHERE [EnteredDate] >= '2019-01-01' 
AND ([CorrespondenceType] = 'IL' OR [CorrespondenceType] = 'OL')
AND ([CorrespondenceType] = 'OL'[EnteredDate]) >[CorrespondenceType] = 'IL',[EnteredDate] +7
```

Comment: Sample data, desired result,  and clarifying your requirement would be tremendously helpful.  That where clause makes no sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would this give you what you need?

```
WITH Get_Data AS
(SELECT  [ID]
,[EnteredDate]
,[CorrespondenceType]
FROM [PRXXXXXXXX] 
WHERE [EnteredDate] >= '2019-01-01' 
And [CorrespondenceType] IN ('IL'. 'OL'))

Select [ID]
, [EnteredDate]
, [CorrespondenceType]
FROM Get_Data
WHERE [CorrespondenceType] = 'IL'
AND [EnteredDate] > (SELECT DATEADD(DAY,7,MAX([EnteredDate])) FROM Get_Data WHERE [CorrespondenceType] = 'OL')
```